# Prettier formatting

Tags: html, prettier

When im formatting, it shows error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected closing tag "a". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags (29:113)
  27 |                 {% endif %}
  28 |                 <br>
> 29 |                 <a href={% url 'edit-post' post.pk %} class="text-light border-3 border-primary-subtle btn">Edit</a>
     |                                                                                                                 ^^^^
  30 |                 <br /><br />
  31 |             </div>
  32 |         </div>
```

it points at the `</a>`

what should i do, i closed it, right?

Comment: Add double quotes around `{% %}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are using Django-templates or jinja

nevertheless, after `href` you should use quotes `"`

Try out below code:

```html
{% endif %}
<br>
<a href="{% url 'edit-post' post.pk %}" class="text-light border-3 border-primary-subtle btn">Edit</a>
                                                                                                               <br /><br />
 </div>
 </div>
```